# what is the difference between . and `` operation in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Request to need a help or information of the two operators . and `` in linux

e.g.

```
    $ cp /home/uddi/root/hello `pwd`

and

$ cp /home/uddi/root/hello .
```

Please suggest me

Comment: `.` isn't an "operator". It means "the current directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small difference occurs after `mkdir /tmp/lost; cd /tmp/lost; rmdir /tmp/lost`.
After these stupid commands `pwd` will be a filename (/tmp/lost) and the current dir `.` does not exist.
I think you want an error when you try to copy a file in the "current" dir, so I would prefer the `.`. It will also avoid an extra command.

Answer (score 2):

When you enclose something between back-ticks, the shell will run the contents and use the output from that/those command/s as an argument for the main command being run. In your example, the shell will run the `pwd` command and use its output as the 2nd argument to the `cp` call.

In your second example, the `.` character is a link to the current directory. The reason that both do the same thing is that `.` links to the current directory and `pwd` will print out the current working directory, which are the same. In this case, you are using two methods to expand to the same path.

EDIT:

You can see somewhat how `.` works by running `ls -a` in any directory. It will show you the `.` and `..` directories, which are filesystem-level links to the current and parent directory, respectively.

Comment: `.` is not "a shortcut for the current working directory" -- it **is** the current directory. See `ls -la`